# Images in public directory aren't be found

Tags: html, css, express

I'm new to express and am trying to load in images from the `public` directory (the same directory of where my CSS files are stored).

I've tried storing the image files in the `public` folder itself, as well as creating an `images` folder in the public director, but am having no luck with either approach.

**Edit:**

The problem is that the images are not visible when loading up the server to view the frontend.

Express Code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Example of CSS code

```
#photogap {
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url("images/photoGapOne.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Folder Directory

```
Test
    public
         CSS
         images
    views
```

Comment: Just tried this, it doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your express config is good.

try this for your css:

```
background: url("/images/photoGapOne.jpg");
```

or maybe

```
background: url("./images/photoGapOne.jpg");
```

AND consider Upper-case letter in your file name. `photoGapOne.jpg`

Comment: Man, the first option worked perfectly!! Can't believe that the issue stemmed from the missing `/`. Thanks man

Comment: your welcome. dont forget to accept my answer ;) @user172127

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the path like this?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

Comment: he want to serve all assets from /public. so it's not good solution